# jQuery Keyup Event Precedence On Multiple Triggers On Same Page

Tags: jquery, events, event-bubbling, keyup

Sorry for the crummy title.

I have a contact form that can pop up on every page. Users can hit Esc to close the form. Works fine.

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" class="open" style="display: block;">
<input id="send" type="hidden" name="send">
<input type="hidden" value="/downloads/" name="_wp_http_referer">
<div id="main">
<input type="hidden" value="mailAction" name="action">
<a class="close" href="#">x</a>
</form>

    jQuery('a.close').click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();   
        jQuery('#overlay').fadeOut( 'slow');
        jQuery('#contactForm').removeClass('open').slideUp();
                                                                        });
    // When the "Escape" key is pressed, close the form
    jQuery('#contactForm').keydown( function( event ) {
        if ( event.which == 27 ) {
            jQuery('#contactForm a.close').trigger('click');
        }
    } );
```

OK. Now on a few other pages, I have another dropdown div that is -not- a form. Again, users can hit Esc to close the form. For -that- I've had to bind the keyup to the document:

```
jQuery(document).keyup( function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 27 ) {
        if( jQuery('#modalpopup').is(':visible') )
          jQuery('#modalpopup .close').trigger('click');
        else if ( jQuery('#myplayer').is(':visible')  )
          jQuery('#myplayer .close').trigger('click');
        }
    } );
```

What happens on these pages is that the keyup never 'bubbles' to the #contactForm. What am I missing? Is there a way to make this second handler 'pass' the keyup event so that it bubbles up to the #contactForm?

Or do I need to wrap those other divs in a dummy form so that they can have independent keyup event handlers?

TIA,

---JC